# How do I add a subproject on which my main project is dependent in Qt?

Tags: qt

I am building a QT project with the following directory structure where all my main app sources and headers are in the top level directory, but I also have a shared library with its own Qt .pro file:

```
main_app_directory
    ├── main_app.pro
    ├── main_app.cpp
    └── my_library
        ├── my_library.pro
        ├── library_file.h
        ├── library_file.cpp
        └── liblibrary_file.so
```

My goal is to be able to run `make` in the `main_app` directory, and have it run `make` in the `my_library` directory before  building `main_app.cpp`.  I understand there that the `SUBDIRS` variable can be specified in a project file, but that I might have to change the directory structure.  I would rather keep the directory structure as is if that is possible.  Is there another way to do this?

Below are my project files:

**main_app.pro**

```
TARGET = main_app
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES = main_app.cpp

LIBS += -Lmy_library -lmy_library
INCLUDEPATH += my_library
```

**my_library.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = library_file

HEADERS += my_library.h
SOURCES += my_library.cpp
```

Comment: You have 2 projects, and you want to compile one before the other so as you point out the solution is to use `TEMPLATE = subdirs` with `CONFIG += ordered` to indicate the compilation order.

Comment: Another possible solution is to create a command in main_app that executes before compiling so that it compiles my_library, but I see that more tedious path.

Comment: @eyllanesc As I understand it, the former would require me to put `main_app.cpp` and `main_app.pro` in another directory, correct?  And how can I specify commands in the project file?

Comment: no, you have to create another .pro where you add the other projects, for example you can take as reference the following example: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/ffb36a13c502cf06f7764822e00644d82e489ee9/50516359

Comment: @eyllanesc, +1 for `CONFIG += ordered`. I didn't knew that one but it is very handy. Thank you!

Comment: If you can put the "main_app" in a subdir project as you have done for the "my_library" subdir project: you should use the `depends` attribute in the root .pro file. Something like this `main_app.depends = my_library`. So you will be able to do a `make` in the root directory and that will build your library before your app. More information here: https://wiki.qt.io/SUBDIRS_-_handling_dependencies

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do this without changing the directory structure of my project.  However, it sounds like that's going to be the only (or at least most recommended) way to do it. Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do it with your actual directory structure. But you can do it with a little change: put your "main_app" in a sub-directory, as you did for the library.

Then you will be able to run qmake / make in the root directory ("test_application" in my example).

```
test_application
  ├── test_application.pro
  ├── main_app
  │     └── main_app.pro
  └── library
        └── library.pro
```

**Solution #1: with "ordered" attribute:**

As eyllanesc explained, you can use the "ordered" attribute and write the file "test_application.pro":

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    library \
    main_app

CONFIG += ordered
```

qmake will follow the order defined in "SUBDIRS" to build "test_application". So you "library" will be built before "main-app".

**Solution #2: with "depends" attribute:**

However, I suggest you to use a more flexible attribute: "depends" in the file  "test_application.pro":

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    library \
    main_app

main_app.depends = library
```

No matter the "SUBDIRS" order, qmake will find alone the correct order to build all your sub-projects. It can be useful in a more complex project with more sub-projects and more dependencies.

In some cases, it can also decrease the compilation time because some projects will be built in parallel.

More information here: https://wiki.qt.io/SUBDIRS_-_handling_dependencies